# How do I insert data into mysql table?

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I am trying to insert data into a mysql database. The connection and the displaying of data works.

But I don't know how to use the `INSERT INTO table` command in C code.

I've tried reading strings with `scanf`/`getchar` to the values in the mysql command, but it didn't work.

How do I insert data into the mysql table after I read the data in my program?

I'm working in Linux.

This is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

static char *host = "localhost";
static char *user = "root";
static char *pass = "PASSWORD";
static char *dbname = "tutorial";

unsigned int port = 3306;
static char *unix_socket = NULL;
unsigned int flag = 0;

int main()
{
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES * res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

if(!(mysql_real_connect(conn, host, user, pass, dbname, port, unix_socket, flag)))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s[%d]", mysql_error(conn), mysql_errno(conn));
    exit(1);
}

mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
res = mysql_store_result(conn);


while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
{
    printf("%s\t%s\n", row[0], row[1]);
}

mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(conn);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tried:

```
...
int id[1] = 5;
char name[8] = "Jack";
...
mysql_query(conn, INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES(id, name);
...
```

Comment: What happens when you try?  Is there an error?

Comment: Not an error, just nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must prepare you C-string before query creation.

You can use [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to do so:

```
#define MAX_STRING 128
char query[MAX_STRING] = {0};
int id = 5;
char name[] = "jack";

snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (%d, '%s')", id, name);

mysql_query(conn, query);
```

As @viraptor pointed out **the solution above has problems with sql injection.**
You should use mysql api (coded to be totally safe) to do the job:

```
#define INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (?,?)";

int id = 5;
char name[] = "jack";
size_t str_length = strlen(name);

MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
if (!stmt)
{
   fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_init(), out of memory\n");
     exit(0);
}
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, INSERT_QUERY, strlen(INSERT_QUERY)))
{
   fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_prepare(), INSERT failed\n");
   fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
   exit(0);
}

MYSQL_BIND bind[2];

/* INTEGER PARAM */
/* This is a number type, so there is no need
   to specify buffer_length */
bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
bind[0].buffer= (char *)&id;
bind[0].is_null= 0;
bind[0].length= 0;

/* STRING PARAM */
bind[1].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[1].buffer= (char *)name;
bind[1].buffer_length= str_length+1;
bind[1].is_null= 0;
bind[1].length= &str_length;

/* Bind the buffers */
if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_bind_param() failed\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}

/* Execute the INSERT statement - 2*/
if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_execute, 2 failed\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}

/* Get the total rows affected */
my_ulonglong affected_rows= mysql_stmt_affected_rows(stmt);
fprintf(stdout, " total affected rows(insert 2): %lu\n",
                (unsigned long) affected_rows);

if (affected_rows != 1) /* validate affected rows */
{
  fprintf(stderr, " invalid affected rows by MySQL\n");
  exit(0);
}

/* Close the statement */
if (mysql_stmt_close(stmt))
{
  fprintf(stderr, " failed while closing the statement\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}
```

You can find reference for this code [at this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html)

Comment: Downvoted, because this has problems with sql injection. mysql has api for passing in values - it's prepared statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html

Comment: @viraptor Well, surely all kind of code performed with literal strings can be easily hacked. BTW I don't think it is the case for OP with such a simple/basic code.

Comment: The strings may be literal at the moment, but possibly not in the future. What's the better option "this is ok right now", or "this is ok even if you change parameters"? It's 2016 and people still constantly fail to fix issues like this. Let's at least keep insecure examples off of SO. If Onur has issues with basics like this, I'd rather he learned about injection as soon as possible.

Comment: @viraptor Well, I totally agree. My fault. Hope my edits are good.

Comment: I'm beginner mysql programming in C. It was so easy in C# but this is so hard. And thank you for answer, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at examples at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html for information how to do this.

In summary, you create a prepared statement, initialize it with `mysql_stmt_prepare`, then pass the values via `mysql_stmt_bind_param`.

You could also construct the text version of the query with values quoted by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html but in that case it's easy to accidentally skip some elements.

Comment: Not the DV, but this answer seems to fall into _link only answer_

Comment: @LPs The example is 30+ lines long. I tried to sum up the functions involved so they're easy to look up. If you can make a shorter example that will make sense here, feel free to propose an edit, or answer yourself :)

Comment: I edited my answer. Take a look if something is wrong. Ty.

Comment: In your first link, is it too long? It's just inserting data, it is can't be so long and complicated.

Comment: @OnurTuralı It is a bit verbose. But they do all the error checking you want to do anyway. And the structures for bind parameters are defined in the code itself, but you can define them at the top of file like `MYSQL_BIND params[] = {{.buffer_type=..., .is_null=...}, {.buffer_type=..., ...}` which makes it a bit more condensed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello So you want to insert data into table but with not directly giving values rather taking input from other source so you can use this type

Here I used snprintf to create a query statement and then execute it

#define MAX_STRING 128;

```
char curr_uname[32]="gamer";
float curr_ran=0.33;
char curr_url[32]="https://www.google.com";

char query[MAX_STRING] = {0};

snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "INSERT INTO redirect_database (username, homepage) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", curr_uname, curr_url);

if (mysql_query(conn, query)!= 0)                   
{                                                                                                  
  fprintf(stderr, "Query Failure\n");                                                              
  return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
}
```